# Where to put invited talks on LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin

I've given a few invited talks that I have up on SlideShare and Youtube that I'd love to showcase on LinkedIn. However, there doesn't seem to be a good place to put these sorts of things. The closest I can see is "publications", but this isn't a publication; it's a presentation. Is there something I'm missing? Is there a "right" way to do this that would make the most sense to the person viewing the profile page?

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to add them now but you can still use the *Projects* or the *Publications* sections to do it. Many have requested this since years ago ([1](https://community.linkedin.com/questions/53430/how-to-add-a-seminar-conference.html), [2](http://community.linkedin.com/questions/21816/id-like-to-list-the-conferences-and-universities-i.html), [3](http://community.linkedin.com/questions/18711/add-talks-you-made.html)), including me, but sadly LinkedIn is just ignoring this lacking feature.

Example (Extract):
[image: List of talks using projects section]